# Linux (Manjaro) inferring QML type from a .py file

Tags: arch-linux, python, qt

First of all, this is my first post, so I hope I'm following the proper guidelines and am stating the issue clearly.

I'm personally not too Linux-savvy, only using it to do some code on occasion, though I do most of that in Windows. To be more precise, I've run into the following issue while running Manjaro on a virtual machine.

Today, while using the PyQt5 library, I noticed a small annoyance. In general, Linux assumes all files ending with .py are python scripts. However, if I happen to have some code which imports PyQt AND has any sort of { brackets, then Manjaro immediately lists it as a "Qt Markup Language" file. Here's some dummy code that replicates the issue saved as "test.py"

```
#!/usr/bin/env python3
from PyQt5 import QtWidgets
some_dict = {}
```

Adding the shebang didn't do much. If I erase either the second OR the third line, the OS says its file type is "Python script", but if I keep both, then it infers it as a QML (Qt Markup Language file), because of the brackets (I assume). This also happens if I format strings with f'' or with .format(), so I know it's not just a dictionary issue.

This has no impact whatsoever on my code, but I still find it mildly annoying and I'd like to know how:

1. Linux infers file types since it doesn't care much for extentions
2. How I can change this if there's a quick solution

Like I said, this is no big deal, especially since I do my editing using the terminal, but it bothers me and makes me curious. Thanks for your help and have a great day!

**UPDATE 1:**
I browsed the wiki and found this: https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/XDG_MIME_Applications#mimeapps.list

I can successfully replicate their example, but so far am having issues adapting this to .py files. Even after I set the new rules, it seems to still browse the configuration files in /usr/share/mime.

**UPDATE 2:**
I'm still unable to write rules that successfully override what's considered a QML when the extention is .py. However, if I replace the import statement with

```
import PyQt5.QtWidgets as QtWidgets
```

then I'm able to "trick" the rules and it now successfully labels it as a "Python Script file". The "issue" itself wasn't solved, but I actually learned a lot from this.

Comment: `In general, Linux assumes all files ending with .py are python scripts` - no, it doesn't. `OS says its file type is "Python script"` - how are you checking it?

Comment: Oh it's just stated in the file manager. Like I said, it's no big deal and I only noticed when I was visually browsing the folder and noticed the different icons and such

Comment: What file manager are you using?

Comment: Oops forgot to specify about. I'm using thunar, which came with my Manjaro (xfce) installation. I guess it's something to do with that then?

Comment: I cannot reproduce with Thunar 1.6.10 - I go to `Properties` and it says `Kind: Python script`.

Comment: I have a more up to date version of thunar, but I doubt that's the issue. Any idea what could be causing this? Regarding of wheter I can easily fox it or not. I don't know if I had this issue yesterday, because I was doing all my coding directly on the terminal, but I can try to roll back the update I did earlier today, if possible, and see if anything changes

Comment: FYI, I can reproduce it with `thunar 1.8.14`

Comment: In relation to your update - does running `update-mime-database` help?

Comment: Forgot to note I did use that command. It seems to add that foo example to the database, but no idea how to edit their example correctly so that it overrides the one it has for python. Based on the mime-type -D command, it seems to look inside the ~/usr/.local/share/mime  folder first, as expected

Comment: I think `mimetype` doesn't use `/usr/share/mime/mime.cache`. But does it report proper MIME type?

Answer (score 2):

> In general, Linux assumes all files ending with .py are python scripts

Linux as the kernel doesn't really care about file endings.  It only
checks whether a file starts with a
[shebang](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Shebang_(Unix)) or some magic
number such as [0x7F followed by ELF(45 4c 46) for
ELF](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Executable_and_Linkable_Format).

I can reproduce this issue with `1.8.14 (Xfce 4.12)` on Slackware 64
-current.  Thunar does not infer file types by itself but uses a
[MIME](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/MIME) database that other
programs use as well:

```
$ grep mime /proc/$(ps -C thunar -o pid:1=)/maps
7f2c3a709000-7f2c3a730000 r--s 00000000 08:01 1055508                    /usr/share/mime/mime.cache
```

You can use `xdg-mime query filetype` or a Perl program called
`mimetype` from `perl-file-mimeinfo` to check a MIME type for a given
file:

```
$ mimetype test.py
test.py: text/x-qml
```

And use `-D` with `mimetype` to check why was the given MIME type chosen:

```
$ mimetype -D test.py
> Data dirs are: /home/ja/.local/share, /usr/local/share, /usr/share
> Checking inode type
> Value "import Qt" at offset 3044 matches at /usr/share/mime/magic line 120
>> Value "{" at offset 3065 matches at /usr/share/mime/magic line 121
test.py: text/x-qml
```

As you see, in this case `mimetype` says that test.py is `text/x-qml`
because it contains `import Qt` *and* curly braces. If test.py looked
like that:

```
#!/usr/bin/env python3

from PyQt5 import QtWidgets
```

`mimetype` reports it's a Python script because even though it can
find `import Qt` there are no curly braces:

```
$ mimetype -D test.py
> Data dirs are: /home/ja/.local/share, /usr/local/share, /usr/share
> Checking inode type
> Value "import Qt" at offset 3044 matches at /usr/share/mime/magic line 120
> Failed nested rules
> Checking globs for basename 'test.py'
> Checking for extension '.py'
test.py: text/x-python
```

What's funny, if `test.py` is renamed to `test.pl` then `mimetype`
claims it's Perl script.

OTOH, `file` says it's a Python script even after renaming it:

```
$ file test.pl
test.py: Python script, ASCII text executable
```

See this answer to read about discrepancies between `mimetype` and `file`: ['file --mime-type' and 'mimetype' Commands Returning Different Results](https://askubuntu.com/questions/279899/file-mime-type-and-mimetype-commands-returning-different-results).

Comment: Thanks for the insight! The link doesn't seem to tell me how to fix the discrepancy, but I may have missed it. I'll do some research now that I know what the underlying issue is. I assume it's not a good idea to edit that file that's reading those values?

Comment: The link only describes why such discrepancies exist. I don't use graphical file managers, or any file manager for that matter preferring command line and mkdir/cp/mv/ls etc. and `file` so I have never needed to modify MIME database that programs use but I think you should feel comfortable editing them or ideally creating new files in `~` that would take precedence over them.

Comment: It's not that big a deal, and personally I tend to use the command line as well since I never do anything major and bigger projects I tend to make in windows anyway. It's just something that's really bugging me and I hate leaving issues (or non-issues even) unaddressed. If I do find the config file and find the right commands, I'll post the solution. Thank you very much for your valuable help!